# Conditional Formating Cell Attributes - Fill Color and Opaqueness

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I´m looking for code syntax that sets the cells color fill opaqueness (lighter or darker) depending on conditions being met or not. The following code goes to the last row of data and works upward toward the first row.

It focuses on a price column and sets a color (black) if the current price is greater than the previous price and sets another color (red) if the current price is lower than the previous price.

In addition, how does one specify colors that are not color constants?

code snippet:

```
'Loop through a recordset from the bottom up and determine
'if current row cell value is greater than the previous one
'recordset sort is descending date (most current date at top)
'go to oldest date and work up until most current date

Public Sub testing()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim thisRow As Integer
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim pastRow As Integer


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
endRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'go to last row and work up

i = endRow

While i >= 1
'Working up the sheet doing whatever

        thisRow = i          'the current row or date under consideration
        nextRow = i - 1      'the row above (next day) - working up
        pastRow = i + 1      'the row below (previous day)

If pastRow < endRow Then     'skip the last row of data, start at 2nd to last
    If nextRow > 0 Then 'as long as there is a tomorrow lets work with today

        'If current day´s value is greater than previous day, 
        'color current day cell (black), else color (Blue)

        If Cells(i, 2).Value > Cells(pastRow, 2).Value Then
            Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.Color _
                 = ColorConstants.vbBlack

            'looking for code to set color intensity (lighter or darker)
            'also how to define a color other than a color constant

        Else
            Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.Color _ 
                 = ColorConstants.vbRed
        End If
    End If
End If

i = i - 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Mac so cannot post a true answer, but in case you are stuck I just wanted to try to help out with what I would do in your shoes :

1. there is such a thing as "conditional formatting" in Excel that enables you to either write simple conditions or more intricate conditions that use formulas (these could call VBA functions). With these, selecting the format is then done through the GUI. This, to me, would be the obvious and easy way to do conditional formatting (instead of VBA).
2. as for custom colors, you have to do that by specifying a custom palette, see for example [How to change the color palette for workbooks in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288412)

Hope this helps,

Tepp

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I need a Excel Mac VBA solution.